# How to add values in dynamic columns in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists in one there are `columns` names which will be dynamic and another list `values` too. how I can map that map to my dataframe `df`. so for this I have give those list as static. but in my program will be dynamic.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ABC', 'LMN', 'XYZ','PQR']
columns = ['LMN','PQR']
values = ['234','654']
```

So far I have tried this

```
for i in range(len(values)):
            df[columns[i]] = np.where(df[columns[i]] == columns[i], values[i], 0)
```

Expected output: -

```
Id  ABC  LMN  XYZ  PQR
0    0   234  0    654
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a Pandas series with elements from list `values` with all the columns in `df` as index and fill-up undefined entries with 0, then append it to `df`, as follows:

```
s = pd.Series(data=values, index=columns).reindex(df.columns).fillna(0)
df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
print(df)


  ABC  LMN XYZ  PQR
0   0  234   0  654
```

We use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) so that the series already has the full set of index corresponding to the full set of columns of `df`.  Consequently, we can fill-up the `NaN` values with 0 before appending to `df`.

---

Alternatively, we can also simplify the steps as follows:

```
s = pd.Series(data=values, index=columns)
df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
```

This version is simpler than the previous version without the need to use [`.reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html).  However, at the `.fillna()` step, it will also fill-up `NaN` values of previous rows.

Depending on whether you want to retain `NaN` values of previous rows or not.  If you don't need to keep `NaN` values of previous rows, this is a simpler version to go for.  Otherwise, the previous version is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by `append()` ,`Dataframe()` and `fillna()` method:

```
df=df.append(pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=[values])).fillna(0)
```

If you print `df` you will get:

```
print(df)
>>>

   ABC  LMN  XYZ  PQR
0  0    234  0    654
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ABC', 'LMN', 'XYZ','PQR'])
columns = ['LMN','PQR']
values = ['234','654']

pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=[values])])

   ABC  LMN  XYZ  PQR
0  NaN  234  NaN  654
```